# P5JS instance mode with sound library is throwing error

Tags: processing, p5.js

Here is my codepen. I was trying to write simple music player using instance mode in p5js but sound extension of p5js causing problems. I don't know how to fix it. Is it a bug in the latest version of p5js?

Also, my devtool  is keep freezing when I use p5js library. ]

Below is the error I get when I include sound lib in [instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode).

```
p5.min.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this._userNode.appendChild is not a function
    at _.l.default.createCanvas (p5.min.js:3)
    at _setup (p5.min.js:3)
    at _runIfPreloadsAreDone (p5.min.js:3)
    at _decrementPreload (p5.min.js:3)
    at _.<anonymous> (p5.sound.min.js:2)
```

here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/xblack/pen/GRqxGNr?editors=1011)

Comment: managed to fix it yet? I'm having the same issue as well.

Comment: the code pen is working now. please check

Comment: I just got the same error. I had to change how I'm linking to the library.

Comment: A [mcve] would be nice, in the question itself, with the relevant library version. Pen currently throws a CORS error. If OP solved their question, a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) would document what they did for future visitors. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen this has been fixed already. I added the codepen in my question.